# Unknown lifecycle phase "java"

Tags: java, docker, maven

I created a Maven project on IntelliJ and it runs correctly.
Now, I would like to launch my project with Docker and without using IntelliJ.

I used this command to launch my project : `docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest mvn clean install`

It comes from the Maven Docker Hub : https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/

With this command, the project is built but does not run. So I add this at the end : `docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation/:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest mvn clean install java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App`

But now, the project is no longer being built:

```sh
[INFO] ------------------< org.exemple.demo:Recommandation >-------------------
[INFO] Building Recommandation 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.201 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-01T08:28:09Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "java". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Here my pom.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Recommandation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.exemple.demo.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Recommandation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can you tell me how to properly execute my Maven project through Docker? I did not find any information to solve this problem by myself.

---

### Edit

Indeed I have already tried with && but I have the impression that because of this, it is the host who executes the command and not the container. Something like this is happening :

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation/:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest mvn clean install
$ java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App
```

`Error: unable to find or load main class target.Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

This is the same problem with `;`

I also tried this : `docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation/:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest bash -c "mvn clean install && java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App"`

```sh
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  41.383 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-01T10:33:16Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class target.Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: target.Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Maven problem.
The way you pass your commands to docker is just a little bit wrong.

Basically your try to execute this command inside your container:

```
mvn clean install java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App
```

If you try to execute this on your Host you will receive the same error as in your container.
You want to execute two separate commands in your container:

1. build your project
2. execute the Jar

To achieve this you have to chain both commands.
Because you only want to execute your JAR-File if the build was successful you have to use the `&&` Operator.

```
mvn clean install && java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App
```

For more details have a look at this Post here:
[10 Useful Chaining Operators in Linux with Practical Examples](https://www.tecmint.com/chaining-operators-in-linux-with-practical-examples/)

BTW. You don't need to execute the `install` goal. `package` should be sufficient.

---

### Edit

As you can now see in your output the project was compiled successfully but your JAR-File could not be executed. This is because you are missing the `-jar` parameter. (I also didn't noticed this in my original answer.)

Therefore you should execute the following command:

```
mvn clean install && java -jar target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App
```

---

### Edit2

Regarding your comment

> Indeed I have already tried with && but I have the impression that because of this, it is the host who executes the command and not the container.

You are completely right - that was kind of misleading explanation by me.
If you want to pass this to the `docker run` command you have to do the following:

```
docker run [your_parameters] maven:latest /bin/bash -c "mvn clean install && java -jar target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with command

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation/:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest mvn clean install java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App
```

Maven thinks it should execute `clean` `install` and than `java` (which is not known to maven)

Try separating with `;`

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation/:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest mvn clean install; java target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App
```

Now if you want to run both commands in Docker, probably better would be wrapping this in a simple bash script and executing from the docker entry point.